# ¿Cómo ejecutar JavaScript desde Google Colab...?

Tags: javascript, google-colab

Muy buenos días

Necesito ejecutar **Javascript** en **Google Colab**, para documentar el código en forma de cuaderno (notebook).

Me podrían ayudar con esta inconveniente.

Gracias..!!!

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia: describe exactamente cuál es el problema que estás teniendo. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elije una de las dos url(elija una).

1. [bit.ly/colabjs](https://bit.ly/colabjs)
2. [colab.to/js](https://colab.to/js)

Tu vas alli.

1. Seleccione Copy to Drive para personalizarlo.
2. Ejecute la primera celda.
3. recargar la pagina
4. Salta la primera celda.
5. Ejecute la segunda celda, luego ejecute los códigos JavaScript que
   desee.

Comment: Muchas gracias .., ya me sirvió.., todo OK....

Comment: Me alegro amigo, te agradecería con un voto